# Sum of Fibonacci Numbers in an Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: summation, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

Let these two be summations of Fibonacci numbers:$$F_{2} + F_{5} + F_{8} + F_{11} + F_{14} +..... + F_{3n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=1} F_{3n-1}$$ and $$F_{0} + F_{3} + F_{6} + F_{9} + F_{12} +..... + F_{3n}=\sum\limits_{n=0} F_{3n}$$

Is there a closed form expression for these summations of Fibonacci numbers?
I've taken a look at the Zeckendorf identities for these but I don't seem to get any useful progress in finding the formula.

Comment: As written, both sums are obviously infinite. You may want to edit your question for the sums to be finite. Also, remember that users in this forum expect you to show your work on the problem.

Comment: This series diverges. Do you want the finite sum?

Comment: Each of your expressions is the sum of two geometric series, one with ratio $\varphi^3$ and one with ration $\varphi^{-3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^nF_{3i-1}=\frac12(F_{3n+1}-1)$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^nF_{3i}=\frac12(F_{3n+2}-1)$$

You can deduce these simply by writing out a few terms; and you can prove them by induction.

Answer (score 0):

*Note :* $$f_n=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt5} \text{ where } \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\text{ and } \psi=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$$

Now $$\sum_{n\geq i\geq1}f_{3i-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\sum_{n\geq i\geq1}\phi^{3i-1}-\psi^{3i-1}\implies$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{1}{\phi}\sum_{n\geq i\geq1}(\phi^3)^i-\frac{1}{\psi}\sum_{n\geq i\geq1}(\psi^3)^i\right)$$

*Note :* Sum of GP is $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ iff $|r|<1$

So , that gives you $$\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{\phi^2(1-\phi^{3n})}{1-\phi^3}-\frac{\psi^2(1-\psi^{3n})}{1-\psi^3}\right)$$

Similarly do for the other one , and then
you can rationalize the denominators to get a bit more clean closed form for Summation of Fibonacci numbers .

Comment: A bit more clean, indeed! $-$ see my answer.

Comment: @TonyK thanx :)